# Flutter: Use custom ErrorWidget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to display (in production) a custom error widget instead of the red screen of death? I will not change the framework code, plus even though we are trying to program without errors, we can't guarantee it to happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to change the default error rendering by changing `ErrorWidget.builder`

```
ErrorWidget.builder = (errorDetails) {
  return Container(color: Colors.red);
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific location where I have to add this snippet of code(like in main, or every build method of page)??

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve here. It's up to you

Comment: It's a static field, just set it in `main()`. Once it's set this handler is used for the whole app until another one is set.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ErrorWidget.builder` instead `main()` function, like this

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => SomethingWrong();
  runApp(YourApp());
}
```

And if you want to show Certain Widget only on Production app, then you can use `kReleaseMode`-

```
  if (kReleaseMode) {
    ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => SomethingWrong();
  }
```

**Note**: The top-level kReleaseMode constant is use to determine whether the app was compiled in release mode.