# In Flutter, How to avoid crash screen by replacing problem content with a text object?

Tags: flutter, crash, handle

I'm now building an app containing some post, as normal each post has title, author, content, photo etc. Everything goes fine but I had the situation in coding that the total screen goes red/crash if for example a data type was mismatch. So, I'm worrying now in later production, if any data goes wrong for whatever reasons(network? user input special characters? etc..), I want just that post replaced with object text like "data error" and all the rest posts displayed as normal.

I guess it relates to some kind of error handling? All I learnt is something like ".catch(print(err))".
Can someone kindly point me the right direction or maybe some sample code?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54864340/5061381)

Comment: thanks guys, you two pointed me to same  place. That one doesn't have details info but I will do some research on that custom ErrorWidget.